# UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion - taking 4 to 6 seconds to launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm building a login module where the credentials entered by the user are validated in a backend system. I'm using an asynchronous call to validate credentials and after user has been authenticated I proceed to next screen using the method `presentViewController:animated:completion`. The problem is that the `presentViewController` method launching is taking an abornal time until presenting the next screen. I’m afraid that my previous call to the `sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:`  is somehow creating a side effect.

Just to make sure when I say 4 – 6 seconds is after the command `presentViewController:animated:completion` is started. I'm saying it because I’m debugging the code and monitoring the moment where the method is called.

First: the `NSURLConnection` method is called:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:10.0];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

Second: `UIViewController` method is called taking an abnormal time running

```
UIViewController *firstViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"];

[self presentViewController:firstViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any help is appreciated.

thanks,
Marcos.

Comment: So are you calling the presentation code from within the completion block?

Comment: yes I'm calling it from the completion block

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a classic symptom of manipulating the UI from a background thread. You need to make sure you only call `UIKit` methods on the main thread. The completion handler isn't guaranteed to be called on any particular thread so you must do something like this:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIViewController *firstViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstView"];
        [self presentViewController:firstViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

This guarantees your code runs on the main thread.